# What does it mean when i2c_smbus_read_byte() returns 0

Tags: i2c, embedded, linux, serial-bus, smbus

i2c_smbus_read_byte() returns a negative value when there is an error in reading data. But what if it returns 0?

Following is the code from adt7316-i2c driver

```
static int adt7316_i2c_read(void *client, u8 reg, u8 *data)
{
   struct i2c_client *cl = client;
   int ret;

   ret = i2c_smbus_write_byte(cl, reg);
   if (ret < 0) {
     dev_err(&cl->dev, "I2C fail to select reg\n");
     return ret;
   }

   ret = i2c_smbus_read_byte(client);
   if (ret < 0) {
      dev_err(&cl->dev, "I2C read error\n");
      return ret;
   }

   *data = ret;

   return 0;
}
```

Even if i2c_smbus_read_byte() returns 0 here then the driver will successfully
probe.
So my main concern is to know whether returing of 0 from i2c_smbus_read_byte() is a valid case or not for a driver to probe.

I am not sure but maybe it means that there is no error and also no data has been read.
If this is the case then under what situation does this happen?

Comment: You should specify what platform this is, but I would assume it's reading a value of zero.

Comment: @Hearth so you mean that a byte was read with a value of 0. For instance, if the input to the adc is 0V. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: You should post your function code. Otherwise we can never be sure what function you are using. If this is based on a library, there must be some documentation which tells you about the return codes of the function.

Comment: @A.R.C., ok I am posting the code. Please check it out.

Comment: See the source code in the Linux kernel

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am developing this adt7316 driver and the IIO maintainer told me that 0 indicates no error but no data read and the code for i2c_smbus_read_byte() function tells something else so there is a confusion going on. Check out this thread [link](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/12/4/1434)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a Linux kernel function and is already being discussed on LKML where it belongs.  LKML makes more sense than any stack exchange site, but within the SE system this would probably go on stackoverflow.

Comment: The commit being reverted there (which you had signed off on) had a zero check created by someone who didn't know what they were doing and who supplied an erroneous commit message falsely claiming that 0 indicates no data read. If your *chip* isn't supposed to reply with a 0 on the bus at that point, that could be an error. But in terms of the I2C function 0 is valid data, as the maintainer is explaining. And anyway, LKML is an authoritative reference on Linux APIs, while this site is only deals with them tangentially.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As explained on LKML a return value of zero indicates that this is the byte received from the I2C bus.  It is *data*, not the *length* of data.

What receiving 0 from the chip *means*, and if the chip is or isn't supposed to be sending a zero is entirely contextual, essentially depending on what question it was asked.

Since the code you depict appears to be a pass-through function that will be used for many purposes, the code can't really know if 0 is or is not valid data, unless you know for a fact that there is no legitimate situation with this chip in which any access could return data of value 0... which seems a bit unlikely, as 0 is actually an extremely common value for configuration or status registers and especially in multi-byte values...

Comment: It's further worth noting that the only way an I2C master can fail to read data is to decide that an actual error has occurred.  If some master's driver is buggy in that it makes this decision but fails to return an error code, that would need to be dealt with in that particular master's driver, not in the driver for a peripheral that could potentially by used with *any* system's I2C master.